# What is this fungus in my raised bed garden?

Tags: identification, fungus, raised-beds, cucumbers

I live on the Gulf Coast. Torrential 1/2 hour rainfalls each day - dropping 2"-3" of rain, then sunny and 80-100% humidity, heat index 100-105F for past 2 weeks.  Spores are beginning to spread to soil.

When you scratch it from wood, it falls to soil as a fine powder.  Soil is very wet except for top 1"-2" that dries by sun each day.

Is this fungus bad for vegetable garden or beneficial to soil breakdown?   Do I need to seek advice to get rid of it? Advice greatly appreciated!
[image: Fungus on wood of raised bed veg garden]